Good reduction for the universal elliptic curve
Let $X$ be a modular curve, i.e. a quotient of the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$ by a congruence subgroup $\Gamma$. When $\Gamma=\Gamma_0(N)$, it is known that $X$ has a smooth model denoted $\mathcal{X}$ over $\mathbb{Z}[1/N]$.
Let $Y\longrightarrow X$ denote the universal elliptic curve. Does $Y$ have a smooth integral model over $\mathbb{Z}[1/N]$? How is this proved?
How do we determine the open $\mathbb{Z}$-subscheme in which the universal family has a smooth integral model for a more general congruence subgroup $\Gamma$?
A reference would also be appreciated!

There is no universal elliptic curve over $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma_0(N)$ because elliptic curves with a cyclic $N$-subgroup can have nontrivial automorphisms.

Thanks for the reply. I do recall that when $\Gamma = \Gamma_0(N)$ there is a coarse moduli space. Are you saying that this coarse moduli space does not have a universal elliptic curve above it?

For a congruence subgroup $\Gamma$ of level $N$, there is a moduli problem associated to $\Gamma$, which can be constructed as follows: Recall that a full level $N$ structure on an elliptic curve $E$ is a basis for $E[N]$. If $\Gamma$ has level $N$, then $\Gamma\supset\Gamma(N)$, and $H := \Gamma/\Gamma(N)$ is a subgroup of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/N)$. The group $H$ acts naturally on full level $N$ structures, and the modular curve $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$ is then a coarse moduli scheme for elliptic curves equipped with an $H$-equivalence class of full level $N$ structures. Another way of saying this is that $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$ is a quotient of $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma(N)$ by $H$.
If $\Gamma$ is torsion-free, so that $\Gamma$ acts freely on $\mathbb{H}$, then $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$ is a fine moduli scheme for the aforementioned moduli problem. I.e., the associated moduli stack is representable by a scheme. (This is the case for $\Gamma_1(N)$ for $N\ge 4$, or $\Gamma(N)$ for $n\ge 3$, and is never the case for $\Gamma_0(N)$. The torsion-free condition is essentially to ensure that the quotient of the universal elliptic curve over $\mathbb{H}$ by $\Gamma$ is an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$, see this question) This moduli stack is, for any $\Gamma$, smooth over $\mathbb{Z}[1/N]$ and admits a universal elliptic curve (which is itself a stack). The moduli stack is representable by a scheme $Y$ if and only if the stack over $\mathbb{C}$ is representable if and only if $\Gamma$ is torsion-free (the first iff is a bit tricky in characteristics 2 and 3. There you can use Deuring's lifting theorem). In this case, $Y$ is a smooth affine $\mathbb{Z}[1/N]$-model of $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$, and its universal elliptic curve is also a scheme. However, this universal elliptic curve is not an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Z}[1/N]$, it is an elliptic curve over (the $\mathbb{Z}[1/N]$-scheme) $Y$.
For many of the standard congruence subgroups, one can extend the moduli problem (by considering "Drinfeld level structures"), and hence $Y$, to characteristics dividing $N$. This results in Katz-Mazur's regular models of $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$ which surject onto $\text{Spec }\mathbb{Z}$. By Theorem 4.7.0 in Katz-Mazur's book, these schemes are fine moduli schemes for the associated moduli problem if and only if the moduli problem is rigid (this means: For any elliptic curve $E/S$, $Aut(E/S)$ acts freely on the set of $\Gamma$-level structures on $E/S$). In fact, by Cor 6.2 in GIT it suffices to check this when $S$ is the spectrum of an alg. closed field.
I'm not sure exactly when you get rigidity (presumably you can find this somewhere in Katz-Mazur), but when you do, you would have a universal elliptic curve over a regular $\mathbb{Z}$-scheme. Note that this $\mathbb{Z}$-scheme would have to have no $\mathbb{Z}$-sections, since any such section would lead to an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Z}$, which does not exist.

Hi Will, thank you for the detailed answer, so you are saying that Deuring's theorem allows one to prove that the universal elliptic curve is an elliptic curve over $Y$?

@kindasorta Deuring's lifting theorem is one way to see that rigidity in characteristic 0 implies rigidity in positive characteristic $p$, at least assuming that $p\nmid N$. I don't think I understand your question -- Which universal elliptic curve are you talking about? If you're talking about the universal elliptic curve over $Y$, then yes, it is, tautologically, an elliptic curve over $Y$.

Ah, basically the fact that the moduli functor is representable by a $\mathbb{Z}[1/N]$-scheme $Y$ means that the identity encodes an elliptic curve $\mathcal{E}$ over $Y$, which is smooth over $\mathbb{Z}[1/S]$, since the composition of the structure maps, $\mathcal{E}\longrightarrow Y\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}[1/N]$ is a composition of smooth morphisms, hence smooth.

How can we see though that the universal elliptic curve coincides with the quotient of the elliptic curve over $\mathbb{H}$ by $\Gamma$? i.e. that the moduli problem interpretation and the geometric construction coincide.

@kindasorta The first step is to consider the quotient by $\Gamma = SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. For this case, you should google the Teichmuller uniformization of the moduli stack of elliptic curves. The analog for $M_g$ is described in the last section of Deligne-Mumford’s paper “irreducibility of moduli spaces…”, where they also cover covers with level structures.

@kindasorta Short answer: the moduli space is the quotient of the Teichmuller space by the mapping class group. For moduli spaces with level structure, you take a quotient by the finite index subgroup of the mapping class group which preserves the level structure.
